# SharePoint designer getting stuck at "communicating with Web service"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

SharePoint designer is getting stuck while opening SharePoint list in Sharepoint designer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Sharepoint Designer Cache and test again:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/

Comment: I deleted the cache but still same issue.

Comment: During I was working with sp 2010 , I have seen same issues. At that time i found corrupted javascript is the reason , it stopped to open SPdesigner. If you place js script on your list pages , remove unwanted script lines and check.

Comment: If your designer crashed, Here is regedit registry solution.. http://sharepointcherie.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-designer-crashes-on-open-site.html  http://sympmarc.com/2013/04/16/sharepoint-designer-2013-crashing-on-open-site-the-fix/